# How I can fix "iio-sensor-proxy" detect orientation problem?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, display, display-settings, sensors

I am a Arch Linux user and I have a  Laptop that has a built in sensor to detect orientation .and according this sensor the screen will be rotate. but the main problem here is that this sensor detect wrongly. this mean when I turn on my Laptop the screen has been rotated to right 90 deg. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way orientation is detected by using a matrix to switch axes and orientations with systemd. You will find a really good [documentation at systemd github project](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/28365e88d0dfc6332b26120e23b2c39b7958f907/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb).